# Django HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have created a basic contact form, and when the user submits information, it should redirect to the "Thank You" page.

**views.py**:

```
def contact(request):
    # if no errors...
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

**urls.py**:

```
(r'^contact/$', contact),
(r'^contact/thanks/$', contact_thanks),
```

Both pages work at the hard-coded URL. However, when I submit the form on `/contact/` it redirects to `/contact` (no ending slash), which is a nonexistent page (either a 404 or an error page telling me I need a slash).

What is the reason it not correctly redirecting, and how can I fix this?

**UPDATE:** the `return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')` is what I now have, but the problem is that the submit button (using POST) does not redirect to the URL -- it doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') ? Are you sure? Shouldn't it be /contact/thanks/?

Comment: would redirect() function work the same as HttpResponseRedirect ?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not the POST button that should redirect, but the view.

If not differently specified, the form (the HTML form tag) POSTs to the same URL. If the form is on /contact/, it POSTs on /contact/ (with or without slash, it's the same).

It's in the view that you should redirect to thanks. From the doc:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Change `/thanks/` to `/contact/thanks/` and you're done.

Comment: How can we send the data using HttpResponseRedirect?

Comment: @MegaBytes: data? what do you mean?

Comment: The data means any information, from one view to another view. e.g. Can We do this way, data = {'xyz': 'abcd', 'ddd':'yyyy'} return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/', data)`. I am new in django, and I reading doc also but I am not getting a way to do it. `render` is one way but I dont want to go to any browser page. just transfer data between views.

Comment: I know this is an old comment, but yes you can send data via the querystring along the lines of this: 

redirect_url = '{redirect_url}?{querystring}'.format(
                redirect_url=reverse("YOUR_VIEW_NAME", kwargs={'named_keywork': obj.pk}),
                querystring=urlencode(
                    {'xyz': 'abcd', 'ddd': 'yyyy'},
                    doseq=True
                )
            )

Comment: we can also use reverse function with django 2.1 (not sure about older versions). Example: `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_name'))`, where view name is specified in `urls.py`

Comment: what happen if user will not wait for message and go to the another page. still message display with redirect to contact page  or getting error?

Answer (score 13):

All of the responses are correct but a better approach is to give names to your URLs in `urls.py` and hint to them in views with reverse function (instead of hard coding URL in views).

**urls.py:**

```
(r'^contact/$', contact, name='contact'),
(r'^contact/thanks/$', contact_thanks, name='thanks'),
```

And hint them in **views.py** like this:

```
from django.urls import reverse

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:thanks'))
```

This is better for future approach and follow [the DRY principle of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry).

Comment: Reverse is great for smaller applications, but can lead to high overhead when working with applications that have large numbers of routes. For example at my company we have a URLs.py file with hundreds of routes, and sub applications that have even more. I'd say all total we have 400-500 or more? Just be mindful of that lookup hit.

Comment: @commadelimited If there are a lot of urls, then `reverse` is overhead. I think hardcoding oif url will cause a bigger overhead for developer later if we change the url

Comment: You'll need this import: `from django.urls import reverse`

Answer (score 5):

I believe that apart from Aviral Dasgupta's solution, OP also needs to change the relative url.

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

to

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
```

`/thanks/` should take the url to root: `yoursite/thanks/` and not `yoursite/contact/thanks/`.

Answer (score 3):

Just try this. It worked for me.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')
```

Note:- Remove the forward slash before

Answer (score 0):

Use the Django [**APPEND_SLASH**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#append-slash) setting.

### APPEND_SLASH

> When set to True, if the request URL
>   does not match any of the patterns in
>   the URLconf and it doesn't end in a
>   slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to
>   the same URL with a slash appended.
>   Note that the redirect may cause any
>   data submitted in a POST request to be
>   lost.

Comment: Isn't the setting True by default? - It is.

Comment: @David542: It might not be the OP's project, or he might have changed it unintentionally.