# Should I use HttpResponseRedirect here?

Tags: python, django

I am doing the Tango with Django tutorial and I have completed the tutorials successfully however I noticed in the [official Django Polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form), the following:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
try:
    selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    # Redisplay the question voting form.
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': p,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
    # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
    # user hits the Back button.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

The part to notice here is the "Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data." However, in the Tango with Django tutorial:

```
def add_page(request, category_name_url):
context = RequestContext(request)

category_name = decode_url(category_name_url)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PageForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        page = form.save(commit=False)

        try:
            cat = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
            page.category = cat
        except Category.DoesNotExist:
            return render_to_response('rango/add_category.html', {}, context)

        page.views = 0
        page.save()

        return category(request, category_name_url)
    else:
        print(form.errors)
else:
    form = PageForm()

return render_to_response('rango/add_page.html',
                         {'category_name_url': category_name_url,
                          'category_name'    : category_name,
                          'form'             : form}, context)
```

Notice the lack of HttpResponseRedirect despite the use of POST data. I don't know if this is correct or not?

I have looked here: [Django HttpResponseRedirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823464/django-httpresponseredirect)

Here: [Django: HttpResponseRedirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647351/django-httpresponseredirect-not-working)

And here: [Django HttpResponseRedirect vs render_to_response - how to get a login form to behave the way I need it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155872/django-httpresponseredirect-vs-render-to-response-how-to-get-a-login-form-to-b)

Also, here: [Django form redirect using HttpResponseRedirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577294/django-form-redirect-using-httpresponseredirect)

And finally here: [Django: What is the difference b/w HttpResponse vs HttpResponseRedirect vs render_to_response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921523/django-what-is-the-difference-b-w-httpresponse-vs-httpresponseredirect-vs-rende)

I still do not understand fully how to use HttpResponseRedirect. Please, help.

Thanks in advance to anyone who responds.

Comment: +1 because you did some very thorough research. :)

Comment: Yes, TWD is unequivocally wrong here. Anyone know if they accept patches?

Comment: @BlueIce I have learned to research before posting. I am not new to forums only new to SO and I apologize for not responsing sooner. I assumed no one was answering my question because I did not get and email or anything. Thanks for all the great responses. I do not know if they accept patches. I brought it up in an issue. Here: https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django/issues/16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common practice to prevent the user resubmitting the form after the initial POST request has been processed server side.

If you don't use HttpResponseRedirect after processing a POST request, the consequences might be that you inadvertently insert multiple duplicate rows into your database or send a confirmation email more than once etc.

Comment: I have to agree with you here. It's just that I am new to Django and still trying to learn. I did the Official tutorial and read Two Scoops and they recommended this as well. I caught some other things in his tutorial as well, like hardcoded urls everywhere. to my understanding this is a terrible practice. Overall, I think TWD is good just not complete. It allows someone to see the building of a website from beginning to end with is not common among online tutorials.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking questions if you are un-sure - happy to help

Answer (score 0):

> Notice the lack of HttpResponseRedirect despite the use of POST data. I don't know if this is correct or not?

Both are "correct" and will work fine. However, preventing re-submission with a redirect is a better approach from a UI design perspective, in case the user hits the back or refresh buttons on their browser.

Comment: Yeah, that is how I understood it from the tutorial. Thanks.